# How to create the following diagonal matrix in Latex?

Tags: matrices

[image]

I want to write the above matrix in Latex. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it by using the pmatrix environment and \dots commands of the mathtools package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} 

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & \dots & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: accurate code, but all the `dots` commands are actually in the basic latex set.  `pmatrix` is in `amsmath`.  nonetheless, loading `mathtools` is probably the best way to go -- it loads `amsmath`, so it's a "one stop shop".

Answer (score 1):

Using `mtpro2` version `[lite]` you can have a best aestetical bracket parens.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} 
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\[
  \PARENS{\begin{matrix}
    a & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & \dots & 1
  \end{matrix}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will prefer the following output:

[image: Output of the above code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{pNiceMatrix}[xdots/shorten=4pt]
    a      & 0      & \Cdots & 0      \\
    0      & 1      & \Cdots & 0      \\
    \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
    0      & 0      & \Cdots & 1
  \end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
A=\begin{pNiceMatrix}[nullify-dots,xdots/line-style=loosely dotted]
\gamma   & \lambda &    0    &        & \Cdots  & 0       \\
\lambda  & \gamma  & \lambda & \Ddots &         & \Vdots  \\
0        & \lambda & \gamma  & \Ddots &         &         \\
         & \Ddots  & \Ddots  & \Ddots &         & 0       \\
\Vdots   &         &         &        &         & \lambda \\
0        & \Cdots  &         & 0      & \lambda & \gamma
\end{pNiceMatrix}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment (what it has common with question?) to complete small document and show us result of it compilation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).